# rewriting unfilled field of the model in Django

Tags: python, django, models

I have a model of object Obj created in django with some fields (A,B,C)
While creating some of the objects in data base people did not fill B field. 
Now I want to filter objects by B, like:
for obj in all_Obj:
    if obj.B = "something":
        obj.delete()

But I am getting this error: users.models.DoesNotExist: Profile matching query does not exist
for the line: if c.main_name.user == user[0]:
The same error I am getting when writing
if not c.main_name.user:
So how can I solve this? I can not rewrite this field because I can not address it and I can not filter by this field to delete some entries I don't need

Thanks a lot for help.. :)

In the request c is concept:

```
class Concept(models.Model):
    partial_url = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    insert_links = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_category = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    main_name = models.ForeignKey('Literal', related_name='concepts', blank=True, null=True,
    unique=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True)
deletion_requests = generic.GenericRelation(DeletionRequest,
        content_type_field='entry_ct', object_id_field='entry_id')
```

And c.main_name is Literal:

```
class Literal(models.Model):
    """Represents particular string literal of the concept"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    norm_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    concept = models.ForeignKey(Concept)
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Unexisting field - user

Comment: can you please post your model code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
YourModel.objects.filter(B='something').delete()
```

or for empty foreign key:

```
YourModel.objects.filter(B__isnull=True).delete()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked :) But how can I access concepts with user field empty to set the user? Just to fix the structure..

Comment: YourModel.objects.filter(B__isnull=True).update(B='something')